# float[] null check in java does not seems to work

Tags: java, android, arrays, null

I have problem with checking is float array null. Here is the code:

```
public float[] lowPass(float[] input, float[] output)
{
    if(null == output) 
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        {
            output[i] = output[i] + ALPHA * (input[i] - output[i]);
            output[i] = input[i] < 0.005f ? 0f : output[i];
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

As you can see this is code for standard lowpass filter that can be found online(I added one line of code). Problem is that it doesn't go through `if` although when I put breakpoint on `return output;` and hower it, it says output = null;
What can be the problem here?

EDIT: Here is the screenshoot of expressions in case you think I'm crazy:
[image]

EDIT2: Here is how I call function

```
if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION)
        {
            if(timeDiff >= updateTreshold)
            {
                accValues = lowPass(event.values.clone(), accValues);
```

before this, accValues is never initialized and it works as I described even when I initialize it with null

Comment: what if `input` is null?

Comment: If it's not going through the `if` statement, that means `output` is not null.  Simple as that.  What do you expect to happen normally?  What are you passing to this method?

Comment: For me your code works normally: if `output` is `null` it goes into the first branch.

Comment: Try using output.equals(null)

Comment: he says he´s got a breakpoint in the last line but never reaches... probably  `input` is null and crashed

Comment: @Avrham Aton you´re so wrong you cannot imagine!

Comment: input is not the problem, that is not null for sure
@makoto yes, that is what you would expect to happen but it didn't happen. I'm passing just declared variable. Now when I think of it, maybe i should iinitiate it with null
But it says null when you check variable value in debugging mode

Comment: @eduyayo that breakpoint is actualy reached, that is where it says output = null

Comment: any eval in eclipse expression view?

Comment: Can you show us an actual call to this function, in a main method? Your initialization might be important.

And @AvrhamAton, if output is null, and you call output.equals(null), you will throw a null pointer exception...

Comment: need more details... Are there any more `output`  named vars arround? could you post the actual call?

Comment: Here is function call accValues = lowPass(event.values.clone(), accValues); What I did is what this guy did here http://www.raweng.com/blog/2013/05/28/applying-low-pass-filter-to-android-sensors-readings/ . And yes I have another output variable but it is in local scope of some other function, that shouldn't be problem

Comment: I still think it's imperative that you post YOUR code, not where you got your code from, or how they call the lowPass() method. There is obviously a problem/discrepancy with your implementation, and likely not theirs (since the comments on the link you provided seemed to be positive).

Comment: That was how I call it, I edited question for more info

Comment: how´d you do it?? if I use this: `public static void main(String[] args) {
  float[] b;
  float[] a = new float[2];
  b = lowPass(a.clone(), b);
 }`... It´s not compiling...

Comment: `output` could be getting set to null in a separate thread

Comment: @Kirby, please, be serious with the guy... he´s in a problem...

Comment: It compiles and run application on my phone

Comment: @eduyayo At least I learned something new :-)

Comment: Members can be used without initialize... I still belive you're seeing collateral modifications... Somehow...

Comment: In the end Kirbi was right...I guess. I have listener registred for two types of sensor events(I'm using single listener for both) and both of them are using this lowPass function. When I put this code in onSensorChanged insted of puting it in separate function it works. But I'm still confused why is this happening?!? OK, maybe this event listener can concurently respond to events and that's ok with me, if it's true. BUT when I call this function in respond to this events I pass different variables and, as far as I know, two threads can't concurently execute same function call, right?